# To replace alternate comas in a string with dots

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone help me with the code to replace the alternate comas in a string to be replace with dots?

Comment: Please be specific. What is it you are having trouble with?

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you can do this two ways:

1. by using the `re` module [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

   `mystring = 'Hello,Joe'
   mystring = re.sub(",", "", mystring)`

2 Or simply:

```
mystring = 'Hello,Joe'
mystring = mystring.replace(",", "")
```

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be more clear in future with questions. I would suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you with understanding the process of creating a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

```
some_string = 'one,two,three,four,five'
new_string = ''

replace = True    # one.two,three.four,five
# replace = False # one,two.three,four.five    

for i in some_string:
    if i == ',' : 
        if replace :
            new_string += '.'
        else:
            new_string += ','

        replace = not replace # logic for alternating

    else:
        new_string += i

print(new_string) # one.two,three.four,five


#----------------------------------------------------

some_string = 'one,two,three,four,five,six'
new_string = ''.join([s+',' if i%2 == 0 else s+'.' for i,s in enumerate(some_string.split(','))])

print(new_string.strip(',').strip('.')) #one,two.three,four.five,six
```